# Conditional Formatting - highlight cells where formula is different?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Is there a way via Conditional Formatting (preferably no VBA, but if it's a *must*, then I'm open to it), to highlight a cell where the formula "idea" is different than the cell above?

I have a column of formulas, but have to manually edit a few of those.  I'd like to have those manually edited formulas highlighted, so when I change the formula for the other cells, I know which cell to skip when updating that column.

For example, here's my column and formulas:

[image]

I'd like to have `B5` highlighted yellow, since the formula is different.

I've tried using `=FORMULATEXT($B3)<>FORMULATEXT($B2)` but that doesn't work, since it's looking at the literal formula text...in which has they're always different. (`=FORMULATEXT(B3)=FORMULATEXT(B2)` will always be `FALSE` since the formula is technically changing, despite it being the same "idea").

I could also perhaps use `=LEN($B3)<>LEN($B2)` but that would have a false positive when the row changes from `9`to `10`, and again from `99` to `100`...

The other option would, of course, just be to work in an `IF()`statement to clarify why I'm doing a different formula, i.e. `=IF(ROW()=5,A5+A4+A2+A1,A5+A4)` and use that...but there's no real logic for why I have to edit manually I could work in - which is why I'd just like a nice visual reminder on those random cells that the formula isn't like the others.

Edit: Quick note that the above formulas are **way** simplified. My actual ones are a little complex.  I'm looking for a general answer to this too. Just thinking for my purposes, I could maybe do a check that if the formula has more than two `+` in it, highlight the cell.  ...but I'm interested in a general way to solve this type of issue that could apply more broadly.

Comment: So the little green triangle in the upper left corner is not sufficient? 8P

Comment: You could use more generic formulas: `=INDEX(A:A,ROW())+INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1)` then you can compare the FORMULATEXT directly.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Haha, that's true. While yes, that would work, it's a large spreadsheet, and it's zoomed out to 55%, so it's pretty easy to miss the green. I've also added a comment already, but would just like something more obvious.  Also, the formula here is way simplified...it's really a `VLOOKUP()`, `COUNTIFS()`, with some `IFERROR()` and the "manual" one includes an additional `COUNTIFS()` or two.

Comment: @pnuts - Great minds think alike - I've actually added a comment. But as I noted, the page is zoomed out a lot so it'd be easy to miss when dragging my updated "regular" formula down.  Perhaps a way to check if a cell has a comment, then highlight? Hmm....

Comment: You don't think I can make that generic with INDEX()? hmmmm.... what little faith you have.  We don't care about the ones manually entered only the ones dragged down.  These are the one we need to use INDEX().  The manual we do not care. They can be entered normally.

Comment: If you set formulas to R1C1 style (Options/Working with formulas) then you will at least remove the differences caused by copying between rows and columns. You'd probably want to toggle this back after seeing the effect though!

Comment: @LordPeter - That's a good thought! I could then probably just use `LEN()` to compare...Except I'd have to keep the workbook `R1C1` for it to work...hmm

Comment: Generally I avoid Conditional Formats since it slows down Excel performance a lot. I think one option would be to read the range .FormulaR1C1 into 2-d array (which is super fast) and loop through it then highlight the cells, but it's VBA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick VB aided solution I came up with.  If I add a comment to the special cells (which I do to explain the formula/why it's different), I can check for a comment then highlight it.

Add this function to the workbook:

```
Function has_Comment(cel As Range) As Boolean
has_Comment = False
If cel.Comment.Text <> "" Then
    has_Comment = True
End If
End Function
```

Then a simple Conditional Formatting formula of:

```
=has_comment(B2)
```

That works, and is relatively simple.

Edit: I found also you can do this, which doesn't rely on a comment. Just points out an `Inconsistency Error`.

```
Function has_inconsistency(cel As Range) As Boolean
has_inconsistency = False
If cel.Errors.Item(xlInconsistentFormula).Value = True Then
    has_inconsistency = True
End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'm sincerely not trying to just answer my own question (especially as I said I am looking for a non VB solution!) - After thinking, and the comments above, just thought to add this as a note/alternative way.

Comment: I think you're stuck with the choices that you didn't really want: VBA or R1C1 references. (Pity that FormulaText doesn't have a flag to specify R1C1)

Comment: @LordPeter - Yeah, unless I create a helper column or two (which I hesitate to do, since my sheet is rather large already).  I've also always been wondering why Excel doesn't have a built-in formula like `=get_R1C1([some A1 style formula or reference])` that would return the R1C1 style of a formula.

Comment: BTW your last UDF can be one line: `has_inconsistency = cel.Errors.Item(xlInconsistentFormula).Value`

Comment: After spending more and more time trying to do a non-VBA solution, I realized non-VBA would be pretty convoluted and hard to maintain.  For now, I'm going with this because I can put it in a `Worksheet Change` even if needed, and it just looks for inconsistent formulas, which is the main thing I was looking for.  But!  **I'm still open to other solutions, if someone has any ideas!**

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option for UDF:

```
Function findDifferent(Rng As Range) As Boolean

findDifferent = Not (Rng.FormulaR1C1 = Rng.Offset(-1).FormulaR1C1 Or Rng.FormulaR1C1 = Rng.Offset(1).FormulaR1C1)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Doesn't even need a helper column. Seems like a lot of work to change the standard alerter triangle to a backcolour though!

Comment: @LordPeter - For now, I'm going with the vba I used below, since it's possible I have three+ formulas in a row that are all different...unless I'm missing something, Scott's just checks above and below (which, admittedly, was what I stated in my OP).

Comment: @BruceWayne that is true.  It only checks above and below one row.